# Как правильно пропустить 2 ViewController'а

Tags: ios, swift, xcode

Подскажите, пожалуйста, что не так?
Есть 3 View:
1) Пользователь выбирает свой пол;
2) Пользователь вводит свой вес.
3) Главный View приложения

После того, как он все это ввел попадает на главный экран приложения.
Хочу сделать так, чтобы пользователь выбирал свой пол и вес только при самом первом запуске приложения. Для этого я создал модель UserSettings, чтобы хранить там введенные значения:

```
final class UserSettings {
enum SettingsKeys: String {
    case userSex
    case userWeight
}

static var userSex: String! {
    get {
        return UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: SettingsKeys.userSex.rawValue)
    } set {
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        let key = SettingsKeys.userSex.rawValue
        if let sex = newValue {
            defaults.set(sex, forKey: key)
        } else {
            defaults.removeObject(forKey: key)
        }
    }
}

static var userWeight: String! {
    get {
        return UserDefaults.standard.string(forKey: SettingsKeys.userWeight.rawValue)
    } set {
        let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
        let key = SettingsKeys.userWeight.rawValue
        if let weight = newValue {
            defaults.set(weight, forKey: key)
        } else {
            defaults.removeObject(forKey: key)
        }
    }
}
```

}

в AppDelegate в функции `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions` прописал:

```
func application(_ application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions [UIApplication.LaunchOptionsKey : Any]? = nil) -> Bool
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    let skipPageSex = defaults.bool(forKey: UserSettings.userSex)
    let skipPageWeight = defaults.bool(forKey: UserSettings.userWeight)

    if skipPageSex && skipPageWeight == true {
        let mainStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let nextView: MainViewController = mainStoryboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "MainViewController") as! MainViewController
        window?.rootViewController = nextView
    } else {
        let firstStoryboard: UIStoryboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let firstView: WelcomeViewController = firstStoryboard.instantiateViewController(identifier: "welcomeVC") as! WelcomeViewController
        window?.rootViewController = firstView
        self.window?.makeKeyAndVisible()
    }
    return true
}
```

Во View выбора пола в экшене кнопки прописал:

```
@IBAction func manSelected(_ sender: UIButton) {    
    sender.setTitle("Man", for: .normal)
    UserSettings.userSex = sender.currentTitle
    let defaults = UserDefaults.standard
    defaults.setValue(true, forKey: UserSettings.userSex)
    defaults.synchronize()
}
```

И то же самое для кнопки с выбором женского пола, только `sender.setTitle("Woman", for: .normal)`

При запуске приложения у меня черный экран с ошибкой Failed to instantiate the default view controller for UIMainStoryboardFile 'Main' - perhaps the designated entry point is not set?
У меня выключена настройка Is Initial View Controller, а если я включаю её, то приложение запускается всегда с самого первого View. Что я делаю не так, подскажите, пожалуйста.

Answer (score 0):

Как минимум, у вас пропущено window?.makeKeyAndVisible() в if. Проверьте также, что в storyboard нужного контроллера указан правильный Storyboard ID.

Comment: Добавил window?.makeKeyAndVisible(). Проверил на указание верных Storyboard ID - все корректно. Is Initial View Controller выключен. Все равно при запуске черный экран Failed to instantiate the default view controller for UIMainStoryboardFile 'Main' - perhaps the designated entry point is not set?

Answer (score 0):

проверьте свойство `window`, оно у вас неверняка `nil`, если вы не устанавливаете initial view controller в сториборд, в этом случае присвойте его вручную перед использованием плюс примените исправление, указанное в другом ответе (`window?.makeKeyAndVisible()`)

```
window = UIWindow(frame:UIScreen.main.bounds)
```

Comment: `window` не `nil`, проверил. `window?.makeKeyAndVisible()` и `window = UIWindow(frame:UIScreen.main.bounds)` добавил - результат не изменился

Answer (score 0):

Судя по всему, в настройках Вашего проекта до сих пор указано, что Вы используете storyboard для создания первого отображаемого `UIViewController`. Убедитесь, что в Info.plist отсутствует параметр `UIMainStoryboardFile` (скорее всего, у Вас он равен `Main`).

Если Вы создавали проект в Xcode 11, то у вас будет сгенерировано много кода для работы с `UIWindowSceneDelegate`. Тогда Вам придётся удалить `UIApplicationSceneManifest` из Info.plist. Удалите также из проекта сгенерированный SceneDelegate.swift.

Возможно, `AppDelegate.window` у Вас всегда равно `nil`. Если это так, то проинициализируйте данное свойство в начале функции `didFinishLaunchingWithOptions` с помощью `window = UIWindow(frame: UIScreen.main.bounds)` (об этом уже было сказано [в ответе @schmidt9](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/1131070/218915)).